# How to get tables which are after specific title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `html` structure like this on a website, and I'm writing a script (`js` on Tampermonkey) which needs to get back **the tables** which are under *"On way go"* but the ones that are under *"On way back"* so I don't know how I can achieve that with a smart way

I've code to show because I've idea for this, maybe there is some jquery selector that would help me bu I don't know all, and haven't find in the doc

It's only composed of 2 `<h4>` and then it can have between 0 and x table, no `id` exists except the span at top, and no distinguishing sign between the tables

```html
<span id="idid">

          <h4 class="spacer">On way go :</h4>
          <table class="traders" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"> <!-- need this -->
             <thead><!-- --></thead>
             <tbody><!-- --></tbody>
         </table> 
          <table class="traders" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"> <!-- need this -->
             <thead><!-- --></thead>
             <tbody><!-- --></tbody>
         </table> 
          
          <h4 class="spacer">On way back</h4>
          <table class="traders" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"> <!-- not this -->
             <thead><!-- --></thead>
             <tbody><!-- --></tbody>
         </table> 
         <table class="traders" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"> <!-- not this -->
             <thead><!-- --></thead>
             <tbody><!-- --></tbody>
         </table> 
    </span>
```

Tip : not my website, no control on structure, I have to work with that

Comment: Ideally, you should put the tables in separate container divs to organize them. Make one div for on way go, and another for on way back. Then you can get the children of one div (which excludes all other elements).

Comment: @clabe45 OP is doing this in Tampermonkey so probably OP desn't have any control on the HTML

Comment: Yes of course that would be perfect and I would have never ask here (I know some things of course) but ... website is not mine, so any control on that

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't understand Tampermonkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `document.evaluate`, search for the text using `xpath` to get the span, then use `nextElementSibling` to get the tables:

```js
let e = document.evaluate("//h4[contains(., 'On way go')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
let first = e.iterateNext();
let el = first.nextElementSibling;
while (el.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'TABLE') {
    console.log(el);
    el = el.nextElementSibling;
}
```

```html
<span id="idid">

          <h4 class="spacer">On way go :</h4>
          <table class="traders" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"> <!-- need this -->
             <thead><!-- --></thead>
             <tbody><!-- --></tbody>
         </table> 
          <table class="traders" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"> <!-- need this -->
             <thead><!-- --></thead>
             <tbody><!-- --></tbody>
         </table> 
          
          <h4 class="spacer">On way back</h4>
          <table class="traders" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"> <!-- not this -->
             <thead><!-- --></thead>
             <tbody><!-- --></tbody>
         </table> 
         <table class="traders" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"> <!-- not this -->
             <thead><!-- --></thead>
             <tbody><!-- --></tbody>
         </table> 
    </span>
```

If you know that the text will be exactly `On way go :`, you could also use `"//h4[text()='On way go :']"` as xpath expression.